# save locations of google map in android for offline uses

Tags: android, google-maps, offline

I implemented `googlemap` to show location of users in my android application. It is working very well while online. But I want to access `google map` for offline uses; like for example, I want to show user's last location on `google map` while the user is offline. If the user goes to online the `google map` will automatically updated.

Is this possible to do in Android App? If so, please suggest me possible ways and useful links.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading an area from Google Maps is certainly doable.

Here's from [Download areas and navigate offline](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6291838?hl=en) docs.

To download an area to use offline, follow the steps below.

> 1. On your phone or tablet, open the Google Maps app maps.
> 2. Make sure you're connected to the Internet and signed in to Google Maps.
> 3. Search for a place, like San Francisco.
> 4. At the bottom, tap the bar that has the name of the place you searched. If you search for a place like a restaurant, tap More three
>      vertical dots.
> 5. Select Download .

Tip: The biggest size for an offline area is 120,000 square kilometers. If you try to save a bigger area, you'll be asked to zoom in to a smaller area.

**Understand cost and data**

Offline areas are free to download, but charges from your service provider still apply.

Downloading a large offline area could use a lot of data and cause your device to run slowly. You can adjust your download preferences in Offline settings.